# Merge sort algorithm advice

Tags: c++, algorithm, merge

I have made a program that sorts a list using a merge sort algorithm.

The problem is that I think it should work but it is not working, the merge function returns a array that was sent as parameter. Can you please see the code I wrote and tell me what is wrong, and how it can be improved.

Thanks

```
void merge_sort(int *niz, int low, int medium, int high) {

int *niz2 = new int[high-low];

int bottom = low;
int top = medium + 1;

for (int f1=low; f1<high-low; f1++) {
    if (low > medium) {
        niz2[f1] = niz[top++];
    }
    else if (top > high) {
        niz2[f1] = niz[bottom++];
    }
    else if (niz[bottom] < niz[top]) {
        niz2[f1] = niz[bottom++];
    }
    else {
        niz2[f1] = niz[top++];
    }
}
niz = niz2;
}

void merge(int *niz, int low, int high) {
if (low < high) {
    int medium = (high+low)/2;
    merge(niz, low, medium);
    merge(niz, medium+1, high);
    merge_sort(niz, low, medium, high);        
}
}
```

The output of program:

```
3 5 2 3 4 9 5 2 7 10 
3 5 2 3 4 9 5 2 7 10
```

Comment: Your naming is wrong. `merge_sort` should be named `merge` and vice versa.

Comment: If you do 'new' somewhere in C++ code then somewhere else should be 'delete' too. Otherwise you run out of memory especially if the new was in recursive functions.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the pointer by value, so the value you assign to `niz` inside function is not visible in caller function.

Your signatures should be 
`void merge(int niz[], int low, int medium, int high)` and
`void merge_sort(int niz[], int low, int high)`.

In `merge` which you have named `merge_sort`, at the bottom, then you should copy back the contents from `niz2` to `niz`, instead of `niz = niz2`.

**EDIT - **
Also you have got the `merge` function wrong (which you have named `merge_sort`). If say you call the function with `low = 100`, `medium = 120`, `high = 140`.

Then `for (int f1=low; f1<high-low; f1++)` would never loop.

It should be `for (int f1=0; f1<high-low; f1++)`. One another consequence of above mistake is `SIGSGV`, because you would be accessing, `niz2` out of bounds (for the given example).

Answer (score 3):

I think there are lots of errors in this code but the biggest one is

```
niz = niz2;
```

Here you are trying to copy the `niz2` array back to `niz`, but it doesn't do that, it just copies the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to assign the contents of `niz2` to `niz` via `niz = niz2;`
.  This is incorrect since `niz` is a pass-by-value pointer, and `niz2` is a local pointer that points to an array.

If you want to copy `niz2` to `niz` you either need a loop like `for (int i = low; i < high; i++) niz[i] = niz2[i]`, use an api function like memcpy to overwrite the input array, or if you're trying to redirect the `int* niz` pointer to use the newly created `niz2` array, then you need to pass the input as a pointer-to-pointer then modify it directly, eg `merge_sort(int** niz, int low...)` and call it via `merge_sort(&niz, 0, 20);`.  Not that if you do modify the input pointer to point to a new array, you should delete the old one first, eg `delete [] *niz; *niz = niz2;`

The statement `niz = niz2;` copies the address pointed to by `niz2` over the temporary `niz` pointer in the parameter list.  When you pass a pointer to a function that recieves an `int*` (such as `foo(int* nPtr);`), the pointer you send is copied into the temporary variable/pointer `nPtr`.  Using `foo(int** nPtr);` tells it that it's working with the 'address of a pointer to and int', not just the 'address of an int'.  In this case you can redirect `nPtr` via a statement like `*nPtr = &tmpInt` or `*nPtr = tmpPtr`.  To get the the actual `int` or data at the source, you'd use `tmpInt = **nPtr`.

Comment: Are you sure that `merge_sort(&niz ...)` is correct way of solving the problem? Wouldn't `niz` end up into a smaller array by this?

Comment: `&niz` is correct if niz is declared as `int* niz`, and the parameter that recieves it is declared `m(int** nizIn,...)`.  Double indirection lets you modify the main pointer itself, not just the data at the end.

Comment: I am not talking about the syntax. I am pointing about the logic. Let size of `niz` be 20. Now if you are merging from [5 .. 10], the `niz` would become a array of size 6.

Comment: As long as niz points to the start of the array segment, and the length is passed (or if niz points to the start of the array proper, and the starting index is passed as well), then it should work.  I haven't really traced how the rest of his code works (some is missing anyway), but I'm just pointing out that double indirection might be a solution to the array copy issue.